# How to redirect URLs that contain uppercase letters to another site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there any `.htaccess` rule to redirect a URL that has uppercase letters to another URL / site?

for example :

```
/Abcgdr
```

or,

```
/aaaAbcgfr
```

redirect to `example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as much a regular expression (regex) question than Apache config, the regex `[A-Z]` (a *character class* containing the range `A` to `Z`) matches any uppercase letter. Regex are case-sensitive by default, so this won't match lowercase letters.

Using a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive you can do the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 [A-Z] https://example.com/
```

This matches any uppercase letter in the URL-path part of the URL (as in your examples) and redirects (302 - temporary) to `https://example.com/`.

---

However, if you have existing mod_rewrite directives, you should consider using mod_rewrite instead. For example, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [A-Z] https://example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This does the same as the mod_alias `RedirectMatch` directive above.

Comment: Awesome ... it works! many thanks for the help :)